# When is the cost incurred for rejecting a contract?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

I've noticed some of the contracts in Kerbal Space Program 0.24 have a fee associated with failure. When is this fee incurred? If I reject it at mission control? After x number of flights?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Contracts have a penalty for *rejecting* and a penalty for *failing*. The first is incurred when rejecting a contract before accepting it. So it is usually a better idea to wait a few (in-game) days until the contracts time out and are replaced with new ones. There is no reputation penalty when unaccepted contracts time out.

An already accepted contract is failed and will make you pay the fail-penalty if:

- You reject it after accepting it
- The time limit is exceeded (it's usually over a year, so this should only be a concern when you do an interplanetary mission)
- For rescue missions, the mission is also failed when you kill the Kerbal you were supposed to rescue.
- For tourist missions, the mission is also failed when you kill one of the tourists or expose them to so much acceleration that they pass out (if g-force is enabled in your game settings).

Answer (score 0):

There are two points at which failure is assessed:

1. When you reject a contract you took.
2. When the time to complete the mission expires, after some time doing what Kerbals do best.  Some contracts don't have an expiry time, so the only way to fail those is to reject the mission.